# Zend Framework Scaffolding Administration Panel

Tags: zend-framework, content-management-system, crud, administration, scaffolding

Is there any crud scaffolding module/framework (like ATK framework) that can be integrated into a Zend Framework based website?
If not... what Zend Framework CMS would you consider? I've googled a lot but didn't find much:
Centurion
Pimcore
TomatoCMS

From documentation Centurion looked easy to learn... what's your opinion?

Thanks.

Comment: I have tested this and it looked promising http://code.google.com/p/zendscaffolding/

Answer (score 1):

Although scaffolding is not is main propose, ZFDatagrid http://code.google.com/p/zfdatagrid has the ability to do that (disclosure: I'm the project owner ).

You can check some demos here:

[Basic listing](http://zfdatagrid.com/grid/)

[Simple CRUD operations](http://zfdatagrid.com/grid/default/site/crud)

[Bulk operations](http://zfdatagrid.com/grid/default/site/form)

Also check the [Project page](http://code.google.com/p/zfdatagrid)

regards,

Comment: That's a great tool. I wonder why it didn't show up during my googling...
Actually I was looking for something more complete... some kind of admin-module based on declarative interface configuration that could be binded to the Models and/or Zend_tables defined in the project.
Zend Framework is supposed to be the most popular mvc framework in php (or at least one of them) and it's unbelievable that there is no tool ready to be plugged in for Administration purposes.
Am I the first one who is experiencing this?
Thanks to anyone who is going to help.

For now thank you Bento!

Comment: @user711643 no, you're not the only one missing that. the whole community is missing it. but it's the community that should build it. so we can only blame ourselves. the even a bit more popular PHP framework symfony has extensive saffolding tools, I read.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the closest solution to my problem: ZFCore opensource CMF based on Zend Framework
http://code.google.com/p/zfcore/

I spent the last 48h reviewing a few opensource CMF based on Zend Framework: during my googling Centurion and Digitalus was spotting everywhere but it looks like are not mantained anymore and anyway even if they look professional and referenced... it was a pain getting them up and running (and Centurion appeared to hang sometimes).
I excluded TomatoCMS, PimCore and Magento becouse I wanted a medium size system completely customizable.

ZFCore is an open source CMF mantained by Anton Shevchuk and other 17 commiters.
It looks very nice and fairly easy to understand besides all the documentation is russian (thanks chrome for translating).

If anyone has a valid alternative, please tell me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to have something similar to ATK with an MVC framework.

If you use Zend_Db and ZF >1.11 you might find this useful http://github.com/elvisciotti/zf1-crud